# Accessing python script on apache server

Tags: jquery, python, apache, cgi, httpd.conf

I am able to call python script on my lamp server using jquery. I need to make some cgi related changes.

Jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
                        url: "classifier_demo.py",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: data,
                        success: function(response) {
                      ....
```

classifier_demo.py start with

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

And I made this cgi related changes

Add a line -

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py
```

into /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf

and also do permission to python file "777" (important)

This was on my localhost,

Now I shifted to ubuntu server, where only apache has been installed.

I checked `locate httpd.conf` which gave `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

But this file is empty. I added

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py
```

in this file, but still jquery to python is not functioning on this server.

Do I need to make any other changes? Or Do I missing anything?

Comment: Why cant you try mod-python http://modpython.org/

Comment: @AkhilThayyil: thanks, I checked it, does it create any confliction woth apache? I appreciate if you can tell how do I use it without any apache changs

Comment: You have to install mod-python library and need to configure apache to load mod_python library and parse python files using that library.
This is similar to the way in which mod_php works. ..

you can refer to the documentation for further details http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/contents.html

Answer (score 1):

`httpd.conf` should work, but note that on Ubuntu most of the config is in various subdirectories. Specifically, all config relating to virtual hosts is in `sites-available` (softlinked in `sites-enabled` using `a2ensite`).

Also, make sure `mod_cgi` is enabled (look if there is `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/cgi.load`. If not, `a2enmod cgi` should do it.

If that also fails... look at `/var/log/apache2/error_log` for hints.

Comment: thanks buddy, there is not `cgi.load` but `cgid.load` which contains `LoadModule cgid_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cgid.so` , what changes should I make here?

Comment: @Amandan: also there is not `/var/log/apache2/error_log` file, also I checked `locate error_log` which gives empty result. Can I see error log anywhere else?